# Changing the order of an 'archive' page

Tags: entries, sorting, ordering, archives

I'm creating a monthly archive page (for a specified year) for a section.

Standard code to output the months and entries as follows:

```
{% set entriesInYear = craft.entries.section('blog').limit(null).after(year).before(year+1) %}

{% for month, entries in entriesInYear | group("postDate|date('F')") %}
    <div class="month">
        <h3>{{ month }}</h3>
        <ul>
            {% for entry in entries %}
                <li>{{ entry.getLink() }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div><!-- month -->
{% endfor %}
```

That's all working perfectly, what I can't figure out is how to reverse the order of the output, so I get January -> December, instead of December -> January.

I'm sure this is simpler than my head is making out, but that will teach me to be coding on a Sunday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your query and sort by ascending postdate, it will start with the oldest and end with the newest:

```
    {% set entriesInYear = craft.entries.section('blog').limit(null).after(year).before(year+1).order('postDate asc') %}
```

Comment: I never even thought about changing the order of the entries, I was too busy trying to change the order of the month groups. Thanks!